# Converting date to ISO-8601 in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, schema.org, microdata

I know that there are many examples of how to convert a date to ISO-8601 format with php, but how would I convert a date to 8601 for search engines but still display the standard date format (May 10, 2015) for users?  I ask for the purpose of structured data markups, which require the dates to be in ISO-8601 format.  I am editing a WordPress template and this is the current php script that posts the date to the page:

```
<?php echo date('F d, Y',strtotime($post_date[0])); ?>
```

So in other words, I'd still like to display the date in the standard format but also generate the date in 8601 format that only crawlers can see, within a markup such as:

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-05-15">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your question is? http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

Comment: So your question is how to get the date additionally in ISO-8601 format in WordPress (although you know that "there are many examples of how to convert" it)?

Comment: Yes.  I want to have the date be automatically converted to the 8601 format but still also display the date in the standard format.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a built in WordPress function:

```
the_time( 'c' )
```

And display like this:

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>">
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Douglas.